# How to point out this to a certain element in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a form. When a input is focused, then the color of label should be blue. But it looks like something is wrong in my code. I am unable to point out this to the input.

Here's the code which doesn't work:

```css
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs: document.querySelector('.input')
  },
  methods: {
    changeColor(){
      this.inputs.previousElementSibling.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <label for="input">Input</label>
 <input type="text" class = "input" v-on:focus = "changeColor"><br /><br />
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```

Here's the code that works:

```css
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs: document.querySelector('.input')
  },
  methods: {
    changeColor(){
      document.querySelector('.input').previousElementSibling.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <label for="input">Input</label>
 <input type="text" class = "input" v-on:focus = "changeColor"><br /><br />
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```

So, my question why this.inputs doesn't work but document.querySelector('.input') works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simpler alternative that gives more flexibility

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: ['styles'],
  methods: {
    changeStyles() {
      this.styles = {
        color: 'blue'    // Add more CSS rules if you want
      }
    },
    restoreStyles() {
      this.styles = {
        color: 'black'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <label :style="styles">Input</label>
  <input type="text" @focus="changeStyles" @focusout="restoreStyles">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps. And the `for` attribute in `label` tag only works with `id` of the bound input field.

Comment: Thanks so much. Props... Got it.

Comment: Forgot.. But Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the console output of this snippet:

```css
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs: document.querySelector('.input')
  },
  methods: {
    changeColor(){
      console.log('Are the similar? answer: ', 
             this.inputs == document.querySelector('.input')); 
      this.inputs.previousElementSibling.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <label for="input">Input</label>
    <input type="text" class = "input" v-on:focus = "changeColor"><br /><br />
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
```

After Vue instance is created it replaces all elements inside the `#app` in its own flavor. Your `inputs` field is set at the moment of creating Vue instance and before mounting the `#app` component. So the thing that you store in the `this.inputs` is long dead!

You should probably read through the [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) very carefully. And as suggested by the @Shreevardhan's answer, you should always use Vue's way to manipulate Vue's stuffs.